# how do i have my discord bot display what a user asked it

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

i am farly new to node js and i am making a talking Ben bot and i want to convert all my commands to slash commands cause it is supposed to be the lastest and greatest. the problem i am having is i don't know how to have the bot say what user and the queston. the code below is what i have so far. how would i define 'person' the user that asked the queston

```
if (name === 'ask') {
    var messages = ['no', 'yes', 'uhh', 'maybe'];
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)
    let message = options.getString('queston')
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`${person} : ${message}\n` + 'Ben : ' + messages[rnd])
    .setColor('RED')
    interaction.reply( { embeds : [ embed]})
  }
```

this is how i registered the command

```
commands.create({
    name:"ask",
    description:"answers any queston you ask",
    options:[
      {
        //requires you to imput a queston
        name:"queston",
        description:"the queston you want ben to answer",
        required:true,
        type: Discord.Constants.ApplicationCommandOptionTypes.STRING
      }
    ]
  })
```

i haven't really been able to find much on this topic so anything will help

Comment: The docs for parsing options are [here](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/parsing-options.html#command-options)

Answer (score 0):

This guide is designed for exactly this...to help you learn and does what you want, echo back what the user input.  Please follow it:

https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/slash-commands.html#before-you-continue

ping/pong is a great way to understand the basics.